# incluir bootstrap no JSFiddle

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsfiddle

Sou iniciante no JSFiddle e não estou conseguindo utilizar bootstrap, já selecionei o jquery, o html5, adicionei bootstrap.min.css no External Resources e não funcionou. Alterei exemplos feitos da Internet e funcionaram perfeitamente, até fiz comparações mas mesmo assim não consegui resolver. acredito que seja a falta de experiência. E como saber a versão do bootstrap?

Comment: Na verdade a sua primeira edição que trouxe a minha solução. Eu estava adicionando somente o "bootstra.min.css(js)", sendo que na verdade tem que ser passado o caminho completo do cdn

Comment: Se possível gostaria que alguém criar a tag jsfiddle para poder ajudar na busca aos iniciantes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para usar o Bootstrap no JSFiddle você tem que incluir em recursos externos:

JS:

```
http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

CSS:

```
http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Ao selecionar jQuery 2.1.0 tem a opção de incluir o Bootstrap 3.2.0 e Bootstrap 2.3.2.